# Change the cache-control time on Azure Website

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service, cache-control

I need to increase the time of the `Cache-control` header for some **static** resources served from an Azure Website. I am using PHP as the language.

Can I do it for an entire folder?
Can I do it for some file extesions (.jpg) ?

Normally you can do this with a simple `.htaccess` but I don't know how to do it in Azure Websites.

I dont want to use the CDN please don't answer that.

Answer (score 3):

Azure Websites uses IIS configuration. To configure `Cache-control` header create a file (or update the one you may already have) called `web.config` and put this in it

This sets `max-age` to 20 days for example

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="20.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

if you want a certain date you can do this, which sets it to expire on August 1st, 2016

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Mon, 01 Aug 2016 00:00:00 GMT" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

for more about the `clientCache` setting in IIS check this page http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache